# Mismatched LInkedEntityId on ContentDocumentLinks

Tags: api, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, emailmessage

I'm trying to link attachment files to Salesforce `EmailMessage`s. Steps so far:

1. Upload attachment file by posting to `/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/ContentVersion`.
2. Query `ContentVersion` table to get corresponding `ContentDocumentId`, e.g., `<doc_id_1>`
3. Post to `/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink` with json body

```
{
  "LinkedEntityId": <email_message_id_1>,
  "ContentDocumentId": <doc_id_1>,
}
```

At this point when I navigate to view `/EmailMessage/<email_message_id_1>/view` in browser I see the file attached. The issue is I want to verify the attachments with the API. If I query

```
services/data/v58.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,+ContentDocumentId,+LinkedEntityId+from+ContentDocumentLink+WHERE+LinkedEntityId=\'<email_message_id_1>\''
```

I get no results, but when I repeat the POST in step 3 above I get a 400 response `Document with ID: <doc_id_1> is already linked with the entity with ID: <email_message_id_1>`. And to make matters weirder, if I query

```
services/data/v58.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,+ContentDocumentId,+LinkedEntityId+from+ContentDocumentLink+WHERE+ContentDocumentId=\'<doc_id_1>\''
```

I get one record linking the content document to `LinkedEntityId=<user_id_1>` where `<user_id_1>` is the user I'm making the API calls as.

Any idea why the `ContentDocumentLink` connecting the document to the email message isn't being returned?

Comment: does the running user have `Salesforce CRM Content` permission or `Query All Files` permission. Note [this Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395050&type=1)

Comment: The user has both `Modify All Data` and `Query All Files`

Comment: long shot -- Ids are case sensitive, a copy-paste error? or, a 15 vs 18 character Id issue

Comment: Turns out the `ContentDocumentLink` objects aren't coming back because the `EmailMessage` object has `Status=5` (draft). If I patch the `EmailMessage` to `Status=3` (sent), the same exact query to the `ContentDocumentLink` table for entries with `LinkedEntityId=<email_message_id_1>` starts returning the expected links.

Comment: Since the attachment files are visible on the email message in browser while it's in draft, there must be some piece of data connecting them. Is it the case that the `ContentDocumentLink` entries exist already but are being filtered out for some reason? Or is there some other object type linking the document and email when the email is in draft? And in the latter case, what object is linking them?